# Not work p5.js in Elementor frontend editor (iframe)

Tags: javascript, canvas, iframe, p5.js, elementor

1. I create canvas element on page, works is fine [home page Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzbXL.jpg)
2. When i want edit this page in Elementor frontend editor, canvas not work, in console error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild') [Screenshot page with canvas in frontend editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sU0kj.jpg)
   Any idea? Thanks!

Code create canvas

HTML

```
<div id="audio_visualizers"></div>
```

JS

```
var pieces, radius, fft, mapMouseX, mapMouseY, toggleBtn, audio, uploadBtn, uploadedAudio, uploadAnim;
var colorPalette = ["#000", "rgba(22, 59, 72, 0.5)", "#00a6e0", "#002a38"];
var uploadLoading = false;
var audioButton = true;
function preload() {
    audio = loadSound("sound/Audio_Visualizers1-1.mp3");
}


function uploaded(file) {
    uploadLoading = true;
    uploadedAudio = loadSound(file.data, uploadedAudioPlay);
}


function uploadedAudioPlay(audioFile) {

    uploadLoading = false;

    if (audio.isPlaying()) {
        audio.pause();
    }

    audio = audioFile;
    audio.loop();
}


function setup() {

    const canvasAudio = createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    canvasAudio.parent('audio_visualizers');

    if (audioButton == true) {

        toggleBtn = createButton("play");

        toggleBtn.addClass("toggle-btn");

        toggleBtn.parent('audio_visualizers');
        
        toggleBtn.mousePressed(toggleAudio);

    } else {
        audio.loop()
    }

    fft = new p5.FFT();

}

function draw() {



    background(colorPalette[0]);

    noFill();

    fft.analyze();

    var bass = fft.getEnergy("bass");
    var treble = fft.getEnergy("treble");
    var mid = fft.getEnergy("mid");

    var mapMid = map(mid, 0, 255, -radius, radius);
    var scaleMid = map(mid, 0, 255, 1, 1.5);

    var mapTreble = map(treble, 0, 255, -radius, radius);
    var scaleTreble = map(treble, 0, 255, 1, 1.5);

    var mapbass = map(bass, 0, 255, -100, 800);
    var scalebass = map(bass, 0, 255, 0, 0.8);

    mapMouseX = map(mouseX, 0, width, 4, 10);
    mapMouseY = map(mouseY, 0, height, windowHeight / 4, windowHeight);

    pieces = mapMouseX;
    radius = mapMouseY;

    translate(windowWidth / 2, windowHeight / 2);

    strokeWeight(1);

    for (i = 0; i < pieces; i += 0.5) {

        rotate(TWO_PI / pieces);


        /*----------  BASS  ----------*/
        push();
        strokeWeight(5);
        stroke(colorPalette[1]);
        scale(scalebass);
        rotate(frameCount * -0.5);
        line(mapbass, radius / 2, radius, radius);
        line(-mapbass, -radius / 2, radius, radius);
        pop();



        /*----------  MID  ----------*/
        push();
        strokeWeight(0.5);
        stroke(colorPalette[2]);
        scale(scaleMid);
        line(mapMid, radius / 2, radius, radius);
        line(-mapMid, -radius / 2, radius, radius);
        pop();


        /*----------  TREMBLE  ----------*/
        push();
        stroke(colorPalette[3]);
        scale(scaleTreble);
        line(mapTreble, radius / 2, radius, radius);
        line(-mapTreble, -radius / 2, radius, radius);
        pop();

    }

}


function toggleAudio() {
    if (audio.isPlaying()) {
        audio.pause();
    } else {
        audio.play();
    }
}


function windowResized() {
    resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}
```

I think in Elementor frontend editor, DOM elements are created in an external window (iframe).It turns out that DOM elements are not created from window.HTMLElement but are created from window.parent.HTMLElement (iframe).

And library  p5.js can't find div element  and create canvas

Register Elementor file script. audio-visualizers-lib with p5.js

```php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', [ $this, 'register_widget_scripts' ] );
// Lib and effects for widget Content Cover
    public function register_widget_scripts() {

        // Effects
        wp_register_script( 'audio-visualizers-effect', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/js/effects/audio-visualizers.min.js', null, 1.0 );

        // Lib
        wp_register_script( 'audio-visualizers-lib', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/js/lib/audio-visualizers.min.js', null, 1.0  );
    
    }
```

Elementor code widget

```php
<?php
namespace Elementor;

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly


class Test_Content_Cover_Widget extends Widget_Base {

    public function get_name() {
        return 'test-content-cover';
    }

    public function get_title() {
        return esc_html__( 'Content Cover', 'test-plugin' );
    }

    public function get_icon() {
        return 'eicon-custom';
    }

    public function get_categories() {
        return array( 'test-category' );
    }

    public function get_keywords() {
        return [ 'effects', 'background'];
    }

    public function get_script_depends() {

        if (\Elementor\Plugin::$instance->editor->is_edit_mode() || \Elementor\Plugin::$instance->preview->is_preview_mode()) {
            return ['audio-visualizers-lib', 'audio-visualizers-effect' ];
        }

        if ( $this->get_settings_for_display( 'background_effects' ) === 'audio_visualizers' ) {
            return [ 'audio-visualizers-lib', 'audio-visualizers-effect' ];
        } 

    }

    /**
     * Register widget controls.
     */

    protected function register_controls() {

        $this->add_control(
            'background_effects', [
                'label' => esc_html__( 'Background Effects', 'test-plugin' ),
                'type' => Controls_Manager::SELECT,
                'options' => [
                    'none' => esc_html__( 'None', 'test-plugin' ),
                    'audio_visualizers' => esc_html__( 'Audio Visualizers', 'test-plugin' ),
                ],
                'default' => 'none',
            ]
        );

        // Audio Visualizers
        $this->add_control(
            'style_audio_visualizers',
            array(
                'label'   => esc_html__( 'Style Audio Visualizers', 'test-plugin' ),
                'type'    => Controls_Manager::CHOOSE,
                'options' => array(
                    'style1_audio_visualizers' => array(
                        'title' => esc_html__( 'Style 1', 'test-plugin' ),
                        'icon'  => 'eicon-paint-brush',
                    ),
                ),
                'condition' => [
                    'background_effects' => 'audio_visualizers',
                ],
                'default' => 'style1_audio_visualizers',
                'toggle'  => false,
            )
        );

        $repeaterAudioVisualizers1 = new \Elementor\Repeater();

        $repeaterAudioVisualizers1->add_control(
            'list_color_audio_visualizers',
            [
                'label' => esc_html__( 'Color', 'test-plugin' ),
                'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::COLOR,
                'alpha' => true,
            ]
        );

        $this->add_control(
            'list_audio_visualizers',
            [
                'label' => esc_html__( 'List colors for Audio Visualizers', 'test-plugin' ),
                'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::REPEATER,
                'fields' => $repeaterAudioVisualizers1->get_controls(),
                'default' => [
                    [
                        'list_color_audio_visualizers' => "#000",
                    ],
                    [
                        'list_color_audio_visualizers' => "rgba(22, 59, 72, 0.5)",
                    ],
                    [
                        'list_color_audio_visualizers' => "#00a6e0",
                    ],
                    [
                        'list_color_audio_visualizers' => "#002a38",
                    ],
                        
                ],
                'condition' => array(
                    'background_effects' => 'audio_visualizers',
                    'style_audio_visualizers' => 'style1_audio_visualizers',
                ),
                'title_field' => '{{{ list_color_audio_visualizers }}}',
            ]
        );

        $this->add_control(
            'file_link_audio_visualizers',
            [
                'label' => esc_html__( 'Upload your track', 'test-plugin' ),
                'type'  => 'file-select',
                'description' => esc_html__( 'Select file from media library or upload', 'test-plugin' ),
                'condition' => array(
                    'background_effects' => 'audio_visualizers',
                ),
            ]
        );

        $this->add_control(
            'button_audio_visualizers',
            array(
                'label'   => esc_html__( 'Button', 'test-plugin' ),
                'type'    => Controls_Manager::SWITCHER,
                'default' => 'yes',
                'condition' => array(
                    'background_effects' => 'audio_visualizers',
                ),
            ),
        );

        $this->add_control(
            'text_audio_visualizers',
            [
                'label' => esc_html__( 'Text button', 'textdomain' ),
                'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::TEXT,
                'default' => esc_html__( 'Play / Pause', 'textdomain' ),
                'condition' => array(
                    'background_effects' => 'audio_visualizers',
                ),
            ]
        );

        $this->end_controls_section();

    }


    protected function render() {

        $settings = $this->get_settings_for_display();
        
        $this->add_render_attribute( 'section', [
            'class' => 'cover-section',
        ] );


        ?>

        <div <?php $this->print_render_attribute_string( 'section' ); ?>>
            
              
                <?php

                // Background Styles


                // Audio Visualizers
                if ( $settings['background_effects'] === 'audio_visualizers' ) {
                    if ( $settings['style_audio_visualizers'] === 'style1_audio_visualizers') {
                        $audio_visualizers_colors = array();
                        if ( $settings['list_audio_visualizers'] ) {
                            foreach (  $settings['list_audio_visualizers'] as $item ) {
                                $audio_visualizers_colors[] = $item['list_color_audio_visualizers'];
                            }
                        }
                        $colors_list_audio_visualizers = implode(",", $audio_visualizers_colors);
                        $audioButton = ( $settings[ 'button_audio_visualizers' ] == 'yes' ? 'true' : 'false' );
                        echo '<div id="effect-box" data-style="'. $settings['style_audio_visualizers'] .'" data-button="'. $audioButton .'" data-audio="'. $settings[ 'file_link_audio_visualizers' ] .'" data-color="'. $colors_list_audio_visualizers .'" data-text="'. $settings[ 'text_audio_visualizers' ] .'"><div id="audio_visualizers"></div></div>';
                    }
                }

                ?>

        </div>

        <?php
    }
}
Plugin::instance()->widgets_manager->register( new Test_Content_Cover_Widget() );
```

**This problem similar with isotope and now problem in p5.js**
https://github.com/metafizzy/isotope/issues/1456

Comment: I asked for clarification on [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77788065/not-work-p5-js-in-elementor-external-window-iframe?noredirect=1#comment137133795_77788065). Same comments apply here. Instead of deleting and reposting, please [edit] your existing question to add clarity. Otherwise, we have to go through the same routine again and the context is gone. Thanks.

Comment: canvas element not display in Elementor frontend editor this is problem.

Comment: I understand that, but that's not clear. Please review the questions I asked in the last question. For starters, I doubt all of this code is necessary to reproduce the error. Beyond that, I've used elementor and canvas and it works fine, so it's not clear to me how you're running the code such that the element can't be found. More clarity is necessary. Is the script and HTML element running as code in an elementor widget? If so, there should be no issue.

Comment: Yes, custom widget with code <div id="audio_visualizers"></div> added on page.

Comment: library p5.js loaded in widget

if (\Elementor\Plugin::$instance->editor->is_edit_mode() || \Elementor\Plugin::$instance->preview->is_preview_mode()) {
   return [  'audio-visualizers-lib', 'audio-visualizers-effect', ];
}

Comment: Please [edit] the question to share your complete elementor code.

Comment: done. full code my widget and code register scripts